# call.on('stream') event fires for some connections and doesn't fire for some other connections

Tags: reactjs, node.js, socket.io, peerjs

I am building a voice chat application with node, socket.io, express, peerjs library and react.

I am able to make the connection while testing with 2 remote computers (PC A and PC B) and 100% of the time, the connection between those two PC's are fine and I get theirs peers connected and running well. Regardless who is the room first.

The issues comes when I've got a third remote computer (PC C) to join the room and tries to connect with any of the other PC, A or B, and they are already in the room. Sometimes, the connection is succesfull and I am able to connect their peers, but sometimes it just won't connect.

If PC A is in the room and PC C joins the room, PC C sees PC A stream, but PC C doesn't see PC A stream.
If PC C is already in the room, it connects well with either, PC A or PC B, all the time and the audio/video connection is stablished.

Bellow the call.on('stream') event the will not trigger sometimes:

```
  socket.on("user-joined", ({ peerId, username }) => {
        const call = myPeer.call(peerId, myStream, {
          metadata: { userName },
        });
        console.log("call", call);
        call.on("stream", (userVideoStream) => {
          console.log("call on stream user join");
          setPeers((prevPeers) => ({
            ...prevPeers,
            [peerId]: {
              stream: userVideoStream,
              userName: username,
            },
          }));
        });
      });
```

I am able to console the call and the call object is always there, it is just sometimes the call.on('stream') event won't fire even if the call object is there.

Bellow is the call.on('stream') event the always triggers after answering:

```
 myPeer.on("call", (call) => {
        console.log("callanswer");
        call.answer(myStream);
        call.on("stream", (userVideoStream) => {
          console.log("call on stream answer");
          setPeers((prevPeers) => ({
            ...prevPeers,
            [call.peer]: {
              stream: userVideoStream,
              userName: call.options.metadata.userName
            },
          }));
       });
```

Here is how I create the peer:

```
const peer = new Peer({
        config: {
          iceServers: [
            { url: "stun:stun.l.google.com:19302" },
            {
              url: "turn:numb.viagenie.ca",
              credential: "muazkh",
              username: "webrtc@live.com",
            },
          ],
        },
        host: "mypeerserver.com",
        path: "/",
        secure: true,
     });
```

What would be the reason the this particular PC is not able to connect and share the stream to another PC that is already inside the room sometimes? I have turned off Firewall on every and each of all 3 PC's, and still won't work. Any suggestion on how I could make PC C connects when joining the room?